# Edit sysctl.conf file

Tags: linux-kernel

Using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga) but I need to change the values for `shmmax` & `shmall`.

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes

kernel.shmmax = 68719476736 

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages

kernel.shmall = 4294967296

fs.suid_dumpable = 1
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744

kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 536870912

kernel.shmmni = 4096
# semaphores: semmsl, semmns, semopm, semmni
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default=262144
net.core.rmem_max=4194304
net.core.wmem_default=262144
net.core.wmem_max=1048586

kernel.shmmax = 4294967295
```

In the above `shmax` is in three times and `shmall` is two times mentioned. Where should I change?

when I type the command `ipcs -lm` it shows

```
[oracle@NTSLSRVDBS02 ~]$ ipcs -lm

------ Shared Memory Limits --------

max number of segments = 4096

max seg size (kbytes) = 4194303

max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608

min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

I need to change the values of `shmmax` and `shmall`.

Comment: Only the last occurrence is used. I recommend people not adding blindly values without checking they are already there. Be aware that there are very specific guidelines for changing these values when installing Oracle.

Comment: @Rahul I assumed it is Oracle, because it is not often enough you see people asking to change those vars at the same time.